# Label does not exist in current context on ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are many questions with same name as this one, but I haven't found solution.

MasterPage.master:

```
<div id="dateShow"> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblDateShow" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

MasterPage.master.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDateShow.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
}
```

It happens on building and show me the error, but if I run without building (before run-->no build) it shows me the date. It happens only in master page with all controls that I want to add, on other pages all work fine. What could be the problem?

Error Message is:

Error   1   The name 'lblDateShow' does not exist in the current context

Long discription:

Warning 2   The type 'MasterPage' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\thegame\6da1e5d1\9152b07\App_Web_tmu2ya5i.4.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'MasterPage' in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\thegame\6da1e5d1\9152b07\App_Web_masterpage.master.cdcab7d2.k9aa16y-.dll'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\thegame\6da1e5d1\9152b07\App_Web_tmu2ya5i.4.cs'.    c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\thegame\6da1e5d1\9152b07\App_Web_tmu2ya5i.4.cs

I tried to delete Temp files, didn't help..

**UPD** I solved that problem. I Had another masterpage2.master and somehow he did all the problems. When I created label or other control, he was declared in second master page, I don't know how can it be))

Comment: Where is lblDateShow declared?

Comment: Sounds to me like lblDateShow is inside of some other container.  Can you post the entire master page markup?

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblDateShow" runat="server"></asp:Label> isn't it a declaration? What u mean?

Comment: What error its showing, can you show us ?

Answer (score 8):

It happend with me and I took some days until discovery that I had one more page with the same code behind (CodeFile="PageName.aspx.cs") wich did not have the control ID. I just deleted it and the problem was deleted together.

Comment: This was happening to me to... somebody had commited a "Copy of xxx.ascx" file and the build server was complaining about the xxx.ascx.cs file. Was a great help.

Answer (score 3):

If `lblDateShow` is in the markup of your master page, but it appears not to exist in the code-behind file, then it is most likely a problem with the designer.cs file for your master page. Is `lblDateShow` instantiated there? If not, you will need to regenerate your designer file or add the Label manually.

Comment: This. You could also try opening the master page in visual studio and then clicking it over to "Design" mode. This frequently seems to regenerate the .designer.cs file.

Comment: This was it, I copy & pasted a page and forgot to change the class name in XXX.aspx.designer.cs code ...

Answer (score 2):

Try putting it in the right namespace. That was my issue